# Array of JSON objects nested in array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, object

I have a JSON array of objects of the format

```
var employees = 
[
  {
    "employee1": "employee1",
    "Details": [
      {
        "title": "Software Engineer",
        "EmployeeId": 451
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "employee2": "employee2",
    "Details": []
  },
  {
    "employee3": "employee3",
    "Details": [
      {
        "title": "Test analyst",
        "EmployeeId": 453
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "employee4": "employee4",
    "Details": [
      {
        "title": "Software engineer",
        "EmployeeId": 487
      },
      {
        "title": "Architect",
        "EmployeeId": 500
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What's the best way to get the EmployeeIds?

Expected output:

```
[451,453,487,500]
```

When I used:

```
console.log(Object.assign({}, ...employees).Details.map(t=>t.EmployeeId))
```

It is returning the result as:

```
[487,500]
```

Is there a way to concatenate other employee Ids in the result?

Comment: first, stop thinking of this as JSON ... it isn't ... it's a javascript object, jSON is a data interchange string format - you'r not dealing with that- do you understand why your attempt didn't work?

Comment: `employees.map(m => m.Details.map(m => m.EmployeeId)).flat()`

Comment: @keith - or `employees.flatMap(m => m.Details.map(m => m.EmployeeId))` :p

Comment: @JaromandaX  Yeah, `flatMap` would be better, I kind of kept it at 2 map's to hopefully point the OP in the direction why his failed.

Comment: @Keith Is there way to find the values without using flatmap or flat? I'm writing this in node version <11 and both functions doesn't work

Comment: @Dev see MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Alternative for alternative

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks. :) console.log(employees.map(m => m.Details.map(m => m.EmployeeId)).reduce((acc,val)=>acc.concat(val),[])) works

Answer (score 5):

Firstly - it's not JSON, just an array. Secondly, use `flatMap` and `map` like so:

```js
var employees = [{
    "employee1": "employee1",
    "Details": [{
      "title": "Software Engineer",
      "EmployeeId": 451
    }]
  },
  {
    "employee2": "employee2",
    "Details": []
  },
  {
    "employee3": "employee3",
    "Details": [{
      "title": "Test analyst",
      "EmployeeId": 453
    }]
  },
  {
    "employee4": "employee4",
    "Details": [{
        "title": "Software engineer",
        "EmployeeId": 487
      },
      {
        "title": "Architect",
        "EmployeeId": 500
      }
    ]
  }
];

var ids = employees.flatMap(({ Details }) => Details.map(({ EmployeeId }) => EmployeeId));

console.log(ids);
```

Polyfill without `flatMap` - courtesy of [MDN's alternative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Alternative):

```js
var employees = [{
    "employee1": "employee1",
    "Details": [{
      "title": "Software Engineer",
      "EmployeeId": 451
    }]
  },
  {
    "employee2": "employee2",
    "Details": []
  },
  {
    "employee3": "employee3",
    "Details": [{
      "title": "Test analyst",
      "EmployeeId": 453
    }]
  },
  {
    "employee4": "employee4",
    "Details": [{
        "title": "Software engineer",
        "EmployeeId": 487
      },
      {
        "title": "Architect",
        "EmployeeId": 500
      }
    ]
  }
];

var ids = employees.reduce((acc, { Details }) => acc.concat(Details.map(({ EmployeeId }) => EmployeeId)), []);

console.log(ids);
```

Comment: Not much browser support for `Array.prototype.flatMap()` unfortunately ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @Phil  I never worry about that, transpile & polyfill.

Comment: It's cool. Just wanted to add a note before you start getting _"it says 'flatMap is not a function'"_

Comment: @Phil I'll add a polyfill to it, don't worry.

Comment: `Array.prototype.flat()` is also not available in Node < 11

Comment: My bad @Phil - I'll add the MDN alternative you posted

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `flatMap` which has questionable support (though I think it's a great answer, mind you) here's an answer that relies on `reduce` and the `spread operator`:

```
employees
  .reduce((a, v) => 
   ( v.Details && a.push(...v.Details.map(o=>o.EmployeeId)), a)
  , []);
```

---

without the `spread`, using `flat`

```
employees
  .reduce((a, v) => 
   ( v.Details && a.push(v.Details.map(o=>o.EmployeeId)), a.flat(1))
  , []);
```

---

without `spread` or `flat`, utilizing `[].concat.apply([], arr)`

```
employees
  .reduce((a, v) => 
   ( v.Details && a.push(v.Details.map(o=>o.EmployeeId)), [].concat.apply([], a))
  , []);
```

---

**Examples of these Working:**

```js
var employees=[{employee1:"employee1",Details:[{title:"Software Engineer",EmployeeId:451}]},{employee2:"employee2",Details:[]},{employee3:"employee3",Details:[{title:"Test analyst",EmployeeId:453}]},{employee4:"employee4",Details:[{title:"Software engineer",EmployeeId:487},{title:"Architect",EmployeeId:500}]}];

let _

// setup our methods and name them

( 
array_concat = employees.reduce((a, v) => ( v.Details && a.push(v.Details.map(o=>o.EmployeeId)), [].concat.apply([], a)), [])
)
.name = "Using Array#concat",

(
spread = employees.reduce((a, v) => ( v.Details && a.push(...v.Details.map(o=>o.EmployeeId)), a), [])
)
.name = "Using Spread Operator",

(
flat = employees.reduce((a, v) => ( v.Details && a.push(v.Details.map(o=>o.EmployeeId)), a.flat(1)), [])
)
.name = "Using Flat",



// test if it works!

isCorrect = (arr, json = JSON.stringify(arr), {name} = arr) => 
console.info( json === "[451,453,487,500]" ? `${name} Passed!` : `${name} Failed`);

isCorrect(array_concat);
isCorrect(spread);
isCorrect(flat);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a nested `reduce` approach. This works quickly and doesn't make use of anything ES5 or higher.

```js
var employees = [{
    "employee1": "employee1",
    "Details": [{
      "title": "Software Engineer",
      "EmployeeId": 451
    }]
  },
  {
    "employee2": "employee2",
    "Details": []
  },
  {
    "employee3": "employee3",
    "Details": [{
      "title": "Test analyst",
      "EmployeeId": 453
    }]
  },
  {
    "employee4": "employee4",
    "Details": [{
        "title": "Software engineer",
        "EmployeeId": 487
      },
      {
        "title": "Architect",
        "EmployeeId": 500
      }
    ]
  }
];

var ids = employees.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return b.Details.reduce(function(c, d) {
        c.push(d.EmployeeId);
        return c;
    }, a);
}, []);

console.log(ids);
```